# CSS div not floating left, conflicting styles?

Tags: html, css, alignment

I'm trying to make a loading bar with two divs, the background bar is grey and the foreground will be green. The bar in the background (.bar) is fine but the green bar (.load) is centered within the   grey bar; it should be aligned left. I am somewhat new to this so I might be overlooking something, any help is appreciated!

if you need more info about the styling just check out the site http://keithtmock.com/ 
it's on the homepage

Here are the CSS properties

```
.bar
{
width:820px;
height:30px;
margin-top:30px;
background-color:gray;
}
.load
{
width:820px;
height:30px;
background-color:green;
transform:scale(.5,1);
-ms-transform:scale(.5,1); /* IE 9 */
-moz-transform:scale(.5,1); /* Firefox */
-webkit-transform:scale(.5,1); /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transform:scale(.5,1); /* Opera */
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="bar">
   <div class="load">
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I should mention i've tried float, align, horizontal-align, margin-left/right, etc. nothing seems to make it budge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because the transform is applied relatively from the middle and the object is not moved afterwards. Use `transform-origin` to fix this:

```
-webkit-transform-origin: 0;
-moz-transform-origin: 0;
-ms-transform-origin: 0;
-o-transform-origin: 0;
transform-origin: 0;
```

Read more about it on [MDN "transform-origin"](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/CSS/transform-origin).

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/jKFqB/).

Comment: I tried this, now it doesn't scale correctly

 -webkit-transform-origin:scale(.5,1);  //example

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution:

```
.bar
{
width:820px;
height:30px;
margin-top:30px;
background-color:gray;


}
.load
{
width:820px;
height:30px;
background-color:green;


transform:scale(.5,1);
-ms-transform:scale(.5,1); /* IE 9 */
-moz-transform:scale(.5,1); /* Firefox */
-webkit-transform:scale(.5,1); /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transform:scale(.5,1); /* Opera */
-webkit-transform-origin: 0;
-moz-transform-origin: 0;
-ms-transform-origin: 0;
-o-transform-origin: 0;
transform-origin: 0;

}
```